# How can I specify user inputs to a shell script that is being run while building a Docker image

Tags: docker

I am currently using a Dockerfile to run 2 shell scripts when building a Docker image. If I don't run either shell script while building the image, but instead start up a container and then run the first shell script, it will ask for two inputs. If I specify the first one as 'root' and the second as '/root', then the various files installed by the first shell script are exactly where the second shell script wants them to be.

How can I write my Dockerfile so that if I attempt to run the first shell script using:

```
   RUN instal_script1.sh
```

It will give 'root' as the response to the first query and '/root' as the response to the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the arguments (separated by `\n`) to the script using a pipe, like this

```
RUN printf 'root\n/root\n' | instal_script1.sh
```

Comment: This will work unless you are using a version of `echo` that writes the string `-e root\n/root`.  Not all echo respond to `-e` the same way.  Use `printf 'root\n/root\n'`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @WilliamPursell. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically run the script instal_script1.sh in the Dockerfile with predefined responses to the prompts, you can use the "echo" command in combination with pipes "|"

```
RUN echo -e "root\n/root" | instal_script1.sh
```